# How to import the Monaco IStandaloneCodeEditor interface correctly in Vue3(Composition API)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, monaco-editor

I encapsulated a component package with monaco，and I met a problem when defining the instance type. I don't know how to import interface IStandaloneCodeEditor | IStandaloneDiffEditor, or I don't have to do it at all.

```
<script lang="ts">
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor";
props: {
  diffEditor: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
  },
  codes: {
    type: String,
    default: () => {
      return "";
    },
  },
  oldCodes: {
    type: String,
    default: () => {
      return "";
    },
  },
  language: {
    type: String,
    default: () => {
      return "json";
    },
  },
  readOnly: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: () => {
      return false;
    },
  },
  theme: {
    type: String,
    default: () => {
      return "vs";
    },
  },
}
setup(props: any) {
  const state = reactive({
    editorInstance: {}   // **How should I define the editorInstance type? IStandaloneCodeEditor or IStandaloneDiffEditor seems correct but I don't know how to import correctly**
  });

  onMounted(() => {
    if (props.diffEditor) {
      state.editorInstance = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(props.containerRef, {
        value: props.codes,
        readOnly: props.readOnly,
        theme: props.theme, 
        ...props.editorOptions,
      });
      
      // **I'm trying to assign type any to state.editorInstance but it doesn't work** 
      (<any>state.editorInstance)!.setModel({
        original: monaco.editor.createModel(props.oldCodes, props.language),
        modified: monaco.editor.createModel(props.codes, props.language),
      });
    } else {
      state.editorInstance = monaco.editor.create(props.containerRef, {
        value: props.codes,
        language: props.language,
        readOnly: props.readOnly,
        theme: props.theme, 
        ...props.editorOptions,
      });
    }
  })

  const getModifiedEditor = () => {
    // I'm trying to assign type any to state.editorInstance but it doesn't work 
    return props.diffEditor ? (<any>state.editorInstance)!.getModifiedEditor() : state.editorInstance;  
    };

  const getOriginalEditor = () => {
    return props.diffEditor ? (<any>state.editorInstance)!.getOriginalEditor() : state.editorInstance;
  };
}
```

I tend to introduce the interface is correct.

I found this in "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.d.ts"

```
export interface IStandaloneCodeEditor extends ICodeEditor {
    updateOptions(newOptions: IEditorOptions & IGlobalEditorOptions): void;
    addCommand(keybinding: number, handler: ICommandHandler, context?: string): string | null;
    createContextKey<T>(key: string, defaultValue: T): IContextKey<T>;
    addAction(descriptor: IActionDescriptor): IDisposable;
}

export interface IStandaloneDiffEditor extends IDiffEditor {
    addCommand(keybinding: number, handler: ICommandHandler, context?: string): string | null;
    createContextKey<T>(key: string, defaultValue: T): IContextKey<T>;
    addAction(descriptor: IActionDescriptor): IDisposable;
    getOriginalEditor(): IStandaloneCodeEditor;
    getModifiedEditor(): IStandaloneCodeEditor;
}
```

and I import like this

```
import {IStandaloneDiffEditor,IStandaloneCodeEditor} from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api";
```

error:

> TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api"' has no exported member 'IStandaloneDiffEditor'.

Answer (score 1):

```
import type monaco from 'monaco-editor';

let monacoEditorInstance: monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor;
```